# set Wallpaper from an Url

Tags: java, android

I have the ability to set the background in my program . 
I want to get a picture from the Internet and set it in the background when clicked on a button .
I was asking anyone for a solution that would suggest that I place the photos in the drawable .
But I do not wanna increase my program volume .
Please, if you have a solution for me . 
Come on and download a picture from the Internet and put it in the background .
I asked one of my friends the solution, suggested the code, but when the button is clicked, The error force close .
If you know where the problem is, tell me
Thanks

```
b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        WallpaperManager mywallpaper =  WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        mywallpaper.getCropAndSetWallpaperIntent(Uri.parse("Url"));
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you try using a AsyncTask to download the picture?

Comment: And please post the EXACT error that you are getting?

Comment: No
How can we use it?
I am newbie ....
  With Async Task, you can download the photo in the background?

Comment: @nima1382na android does not allow network activity on the user interface thread, the best way to download something would be to use a AsyncTask which will run the code that downloads the photo on a background thread. Here is the link that helps you use a AsyncTask https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Thank you all
You helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Android does not allow you to perform network operation on the main UI thread starting with android honeycomb 3.0, see this link for more details https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

The proper way to download a Image would be to use a AsyncTask to download the wallpaper and then call the method that sets the wall paper in the `onPostExecute(Result result)` of the AsyncTask, since that method runs on the UI thread.

Here would be a framework for your AsyncTask

```
private class DownloadPictureTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Bitmap> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
   //this method runs on the background thread and downloads a bitmap
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      try {

    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) ( new URL(url)).openConnection();
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.connect();

    InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    return myBitmap;
       }
catch(Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
    return null;
                    }

 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {
     //put code here if you want to update the progress of the download on the ui
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
     //this runs on the Ui thread, put code here to set the imageview such as the following:
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
 }
}
```

Comment: I added how to download the image in the async task

Answer (score 0):

Get the Bitmap from the give url and and set the image.

Example Code:

```
public Bitmap downloadImage() {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) ( new URL(url)).openConnection();
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.connect();

        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        return myBitmap;
    }
    catch(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }


}
```

To set the bitmap in imageview:-

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

Comment: you can't perform network operations on the main thread. I believe this is the OP's problem

Comment: I know use Async. I think everybody have this commonsense if you are codding in Android.

Comment: it's true . I also want to use Async Tosk little. If you know how to download a photo with ASK TOSK and place it in the background, please help me.

Comment: Call above method in doInBackground() after call below code in postExecute()

Answer (score 0):

You can use any image loader and after loading or downloading you can set bitmap as your wallpaper, Please check following example

```
public void setWallpaperFromUrl(String imgUrl){
       ImageView imageView=new ImageView(this);
       ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imgUrl, imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
           @Override
           public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

           }


           @Override
           public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

           }

           @Override
           public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
               WallpaperManager wallManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(AppApplication.getAppContext());
               try {
                   //wallManager.setBitmap(loadedImage);
                   wallManager.setBitmap(loadedImage);

                   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Wallpaper Set Successfully!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Setting WallPaper Failed!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           }
       });
   }
```

More about universal Image Loader : https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader